# Activity with two intent filters restarts, but the main intent-filter is not called when restarting, other intentet filter is called

Tags: android, android-intent

There are two intents for an activity. `android.intent.action.MAIN`, and `android.intent.action.VIEW`. Now consider a situation of app crash, then the app restarts automatically. but the intent used in restarting is not the main intent-filter (`android.intent.action.MAIN`). I want to restart the app by this intent (`android.intent.action.MAIN`).

here is my activity in intent

```
     <activity
        android:name=".login.Login"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        .....
        .....



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:scheme="content"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.asdf"
                tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

here is the Oncreate() method:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        if (data != null) {
            getIntent().setData(null);
            try {
                importData(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // warn user about bad data here
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
......
.....
...

}
```

here is the onNewIntent()

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Uri data = intent.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        getIntent().setData(null);
        try {
            importData(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // warn user about bad data here
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login Activity had two intent filters as follows.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data
                android:scheme="content"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.asdf"
                tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but, when the Login Activity is launched by the second intent-filter and when I restart the app, it launches through the second intent-filter. that was the problem I had and what I wanted to do is open the activity using the first intent-filter when it gets restart.

I could solve this problem by adding the below line in Manifest file under login Activity`as follows.
line-->

```
android:noHistory="true"
```